# Compile a C program using OpenMP into a shared library?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, openmp

I have a C program that uses basic OpenMP functionality. For instance,

```
// foo.c
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double foo(int n){
    int i;
    double s = 0.0;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:s) 
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        printf("Thread %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
        s += i;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Then it works OK if I include `foo.c` directly in `main_1.c`, which is

```
//main_1.c
#include "foo.c"
int main(){
    double s = foo(10);
    printf("Sum = %g\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Then `gcc -fopenmp main_1.c && ./a.out` yields

```
Thread 0
Thread 3
Thread 1
Thread 2
Thread 0
Thread 3
Thread 1
Thread 2
Thread 0
Thread 1
Sum = 45
```

My question is if I'd like to compile `foo.c` into a shared library first and then use it later, how can I make the OpenMP work? I have tried the following steps, which fails to use multi-threads. I compile `foo.c` into a shared library by first

```
gcc -c -fpic foo.c -fopenmp
```

and then

```
gcc -shared -fopenmp foo.o -o libfoo.so
```

to get `libfoo.so`. I then write a header file `foo.h`,

```
//foo.h
#ifndef foo_h__
#define foo_h__

double foo(int);

#endif  // foo_h__
```

include it in `main_2.c`

```
//main_2.c
#include "foo.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main(){
    double s = foo(10);
    printf("Sum = %g\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

and then compile by

```
gcc -L/path/to/foo_h main_2.c -lfoo && ./a.out
```

The output becomes

```
Thread 0
Thread 0
Thread 0
Thread 0
Thread 0
Thread 0
Thread 0
Thread 0
Thread 0
Thread 0
Sum = 45
```

Clearly something is wrong but I couldn't figure it out.

**UPDATE:** I've found that when I compiled `foo.c` into a shared library, I didn't do EXACTLY as I described in the original question. What I did was

```
gcc -c -fPIC foo.c
```

rather than

```
gcc -c -fPIC -fopenmp foo.c
```

Now it works. In addition, I add the flag `-Wall` to see what's happening:

```
gcc -c -fPIC -Wall foo.c
```

yields

```
foo.c: In function ‘foo’:
foo.c:8:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]
     #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:s)
 ^
```

This explains all! I apologize for the confusion and thanks for everyone who made comments!

Comment: Works for me. Make sure there is no other `libfoo.so` somewhere in the RTLD library path (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`). Running with `LD_DEBUG=libs` could help diagnose such cases.

Comment: Yeah, it works for me also.

Comment: I did `gcc main_2.c -lfoo -L.` What does `ldd libfoo.so` and `ldd a.out` show?

Comment: works fine for me with gcc 4.8.2.
Can you try adding schedule(static,1) to the openmp directive to force openmp to hand the work out to all threads?

Comment: I made a careless mistake when I typed the compilation commands on my computer. The flag `-fopenmp` was missed when I complied `foo.c` into `foo.o` and since I didn't use `-Wall`, the compiler didn't warn me. I've updated my question.